# Python Multiprocessing Pool stalling / zombie children

Tags: python, multiprocessing, chess, zombie-process

So I'm working on an iterative deepening multitprocess chess search
algorithm and it works currently. Unfortunately sometimes the program stalls somewherein the except block. When it stalls there will be 7 zombie children (I'm running on an 8 core machine so I create 7 processes). This is fairly rare to happen but it will happen a couple times per thousand moves it seems when my program is actually playing.

It seems to only happen on linux/mac machines. I'm looking to have my search stop after 10 seconds and return the values from the previous movelist.

Any suggestions on how to go about debugging or fixing this problem?

```
def search(board, maxDepth, maxTime):
    start = time.time()

    threadData = [[i, None, 0, board] for i in board.legal_moves]
    threads = min(len(threadData), cpu_count()-1)
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=threads)
    moveList = []
    gotDepth = -1
    for depth in range(0, maxDepth):
        # set the current depth to search
        for i in range(len(threadData)):
            threadData[i][2] = depth

        result = pool.map_async(moveThreading, threadData)

        try:
            threadData = result.get(maxTime - (time.time() - start))
            gotDepth = depth
            threadData = sorted(threadData, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
            moveList = [[item[0], item[1]] for item in threadData]
        except TimeoutError:
            #Diagnostic printing for analysis after game is played
            if DIAGNOSTIC:
                with open("diagnostic.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write("@"+str(depth-1)+'==')
                    for i in moveList:
                        f.write("['"+str(i[0])+"'_"+str(i[1])+']')
                    f.write('\n')
            pool.terminate()
            pool.join()
            pool = None
            break

    return gotDepth, moveList
```

Comment: Side-note: You're aware that, on CPython, [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) makes threads largely useless unless the work is being performed in C extension modules, or you're multithreading to deal with blocking I/O? Otherwise, especially on Python 2, CPU bound multithreaded code will run slower than single threaded equivalent code.

Comment: Sorry for not being consistent. I'm using multiprocessing not multithreading. 

Using this, running on python 3.5
"from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool, Process, Array, Value, TimeoutError"

Comment: That's just misleading. There actually is a `ThreadPool` class, undocumented by name but widely known (it's what you get if you import `Pool` from `multiprocessing.dummy`, the `multiprocessing` API implemented using `threading`), so the name choice was extra unfortunate. Either way, least it means you're not wasting your time just to get worse performance. :-)

Comment: Yeah I already encountered that haha ;)

Comment: Dumb suggestion: Add some debug prints before and after the loop, `terminate` and `join` calls, and see where it hangs? Also, this use case may map somewhat better to [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), so you can explicitly cancel the future objects remaining if `concurrent.future.wait` times out before they all complete. My only hunch is that the result object may not be cancelling tasks when it times out, but possibly also not continuing to properly collect results, and some queue may be filling up such that new tasks can't be dispatched.

Comment: `concurrent.futures` where the `Future`s are managed both independently and collectively and can be explicitly cancelled might deal with the hypothetical issue I mentioned.

Comment: Oh,  and side-note: Given that the work done by the main process while the workers are processing is "collect results from child processes", you probably just want to use `cpu_count()` for the `Pool` size, not `cpu_count() - 1`. Otherwise, you leave a core mostly idling to handle the main process, even though it's doing very little CPU-wise; better to launch a worker for every core and ensure (assuming the tasks aren't dwarfed by IPC) they're fully occupied.

Comment: I'm in the process of running it with print statements before and after the terminate and join calls. The problem is since it's sort of rare, it's taking awhile for it to even happen again. 

I'll look into the concurrent.futures though. Thanks.

Comment: I finally got it to happen and it looks like it gets stuck on the pool.terminate() line of code with 7 zombie processes still there.